# Window Message Font in MapBasic

Tags: mapbasic, font

How can I write texts with different colors per text in the same window message using  MapBasic?

Comment: Why would you need different text colours?

Answer (score 2):

The message window in MapInfo Pro only supports one text style (font, colour and size), so I can't see that you can do this.

You could create your own custom message window thru .NET and use this instead.

Comment: I don't Know how?